# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'SecretParam' of gcloud param defineSecret in typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables, gcloud

I am writing a firestore function for which I want to set some secrets.
I read in the firebase documentation how to set up a secret param:

```
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#secret_parameters
```

so I tried it that way:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import {defineSecret} from 'firebase-functions/params';
const someToken = defineSecret("TOKEN_NAME");

import * as express from "express";
import {bootstrap, services} from "./bootstrap";


export const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    res.send("json body missing!");
    return;
  }

  await bootstrap(someToken.value());

  services.useGraphQL?.getEntity(req.body).then(
      (response) => {
        res.status(200).send(response);
      },
      () => {
        console.error(`Error while ${req.body.command}`);
        res.sendStatus(500);
      });
}
);

export default functions
    .runWith({secrets: ["TOKEN_NAME"]})
    .https.onRequest(app);
```

My problem / question is, that "someToken.value()" throws the error "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'SecretParam' ". So what am I doing wrong? What can I do to do it correctly?

I tried to read the value of the Object differently, but everything else resolved in more type errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing secrets they are added as environment variables for the cloud function. They can be accessed through `process.env.MY_SECRET` in this example.

Also, have you JSON serialised the `someToken` object and logged it? That would enabled you to see what the object structure was and potentially reveal the object key useable if the above doesn't work.

Comment: Yes thank you! You were right, I just removed 

```
import {defineSecret} from 'firebase-functions/params';
const someToken = defineSecret("TOKEN_NAME");
```

and set:
```
 await bootstrap(process.env.TOKEN);
```

and it worked. way simpler as before.